# Jhipster consuming lots of resources

Tags: mysql, performance, vps, netstat, jhipster

I have deployed a Jhipster application on a VPS (OVH) with tomcat7 installed on it.
Since a few days, the application seems to be very slow.
Once I launch tomcat, I do a netstat -tanpu and I m getting these connections :

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      28624/mysqld    
tcp        0      0 xx.xx.xx.xxx:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      630/named       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.2:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      630/named       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      630/named       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      518/sshd        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      630/named       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          127.0.0.1:42242         ESTABLISHED 28624/mysqld    
tcp        0      0 xx.xx.xx.xxx:42991     xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:443       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          127.0.0.1:42214         ESTABLISHED 28624/mysqld    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          127.0.0.1:42230         ESTABLISHED 28624/mysqld    
tcp        0      0 xx.xx.xx.xxx:40691     xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:443       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          127.0.0.1:42231         ESTABLISHED 28624/mysqld    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          127.0.0.1:42227         ESTABLISHED 28624/mysqld    
tcp        0      0 xx.xx.xx.xxx:43299     xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:7070      ESTABLISHED 16013/ipv6      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          127.0.0.1:42226         ESTABLISHED 28624/mysqld    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          127.0.0.1:42232         ESTABLISHED 28624/mysqld    
tcp        0      0 xx.xx.xx.xxx:22        xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:52459    ESTABLISHED 25718/sshd: root@no
tcp        0     36 xx.xx.xx.xxx:22        xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:22036    ESTABLISHED 25941/0         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          127.0.0.1:42234         ESTABLISHED 28624/mysqld    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          127.0.0.1:42238         ESTABLISHED 28624/mysqld    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          127.0.0.1:42228         ESTABLISHED 28624/mysqld    
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      26207/java      
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN      630/named       
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      518/sshd        
tcp6       0      0 ::1:953                 :::*                    LISTEN      630/named       
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN      26207/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:42214         127.0.0.1:3306          ESTABLISHED 26207/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:42231         127.0.0.1:3306          ESTABLISHED 26207/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:42238         127.0.0.1:3306          ESTABLISHED 26207/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:42232         127.0.0.1:3306          ESTABLISHED 26207/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:42228         127.0.0.1:3306          ESTABLISHED 26207/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:42227         127.0.0.1:3306          ESTABLISHED 26207/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:42234         127.0.0.1:3306          ESTABLISHED 26207/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:42230         127.0.0.1:3306          ESTABLISHED 26207/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:42242         127.0.0.1:3306          ESTABLISHED 26207/java      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:42226         127.0.0.1:3306          ESTABLISHED 26207/java      
udp        0      0 xx.xx.xx.xxx:53        0.0.0.0:*                           630/named       
udp        0      0 127.0.0.2:53            0.0.0.0:*                           630/named       
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           630/named       
udp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                                630/named
```

I am wondering if my problem can be related to the many connections to 127.0.0.1:3306  and xx.xx.xxx.xxx:8080  (java and mysqld)

Answer (score 1):

There's a connection pool, so you could have several connections opened without causing any specific issue.

You can check the state of the connection pool in the "monitoring" screen, and of course you can run JConsole to have more detailed information (we are using HikariCP, which export a lot of data via JMX)

Comment: I don't know if it's accessible through JHipster yet or not, but HikariCP 2.3.2 added support for Dropwizard/Codahale HealthChecks (also exposable through JMX).  And since 2.2.0 we have support for Dropwizard/Codahale Metrics for monitoring trends, etc. as well.